# iOS WKWebView is destroying picture/video quality on upload from iphone

Tags: javascript, html, swift, mobile-safari

In our app we use WKWebView to display web content. Whenever I upload a picture/video using `<input file="type"/>` i get prompted to "select from photo library", "take a picture/video" or to "choose file". However, when i do choose a photo/video from the photo library or even take a photo/video with the camera and select it and attach it - the photo/video quality becomes really bad on the server.

I tested this on mobile safari, but whenever i attach an image/video or take it through the camera the attachment turns out fine and the quality is fine on the server. Is WKWebView somehow messing with the image quality during attaching the image/video? I've been ripping my hair out trying to find a solution to this issue. Please help!